# Angular forms cannot be tested

Tags: javascript, html, angular, testing

I am a beginner tester in Angular and I am using Jasmine for unit testing.
I have a [template driven form](https://angular.io/guide/forms) like this:

```html
<form name="editForm" role="form"  novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" #editForm="ngForm">

    <div class="modal-header">
       .....
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="half-block">
            <div class="form-group half-item">
                <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="oncosupApp.paciente.nombre" for="field_nombre">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="field_nombre"
                    [(ngModel)]="paciente.nombre" required/>
                <div [hidden]="!(editForm.controls.nombre?.dirty && editForm.controls.nombre?.invalid)">
                    <small class="form-text text-danger"
                       [hidden]="!editForm.controls.nombre?.errors?.required" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.required">
                       This field is required.
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>


          ...........
```

Now I want to unit test it, but the probem is that I do not find any tutorial on how to test template driven forms. According to angular [Testing Model Driven Forms](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/model-driven-forms/) these kind of forms cannot be unit tested:

> TIP:With template driven forms the state is in the view and unless the component has a reference to the template form with a ViewChild
>   decorator there is no way to test the form using a unit test. We would
>   have to perform a full E2E test simulating button clicks and typing in
>   values into forms.

I would appreciate if somebody that has had the same problem would share the solution with me, on how to test the validation of this form. Not very detailed but I only want to check if th efields really apear and if the submit button saves the data.

I have this model.ts that has its own imports and this code:

```html
export class Paciente implements BaseEntity {
    constructor(

        public nombre?: string,
        ....
```

And one of teh specs where I want to create a new object is here:

```html
  it('Should call create service on save for new entity',
                inject([],
                    fakeAsync(() => { //assync is used to let all the assync code to finish before continuing
                        // GIVEN
                        const entity = new Paciente('anna');//here is a NOMBRE THAT i WANT TO CHECK IF ITS FIELD APPEARS IN TEH FORM OR NOT
                        spyOn(service, 'create').and.returnValue(Observable.of(new HttpResponse({body: entity})));
                        comp.paciente = entity;
                        // WHEN
                        comp.save();
                        tick(); // simulate async

                        // THEN
                        expect(service.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(entity);
                        expect(comp.isSaving).toEqual(false);
                        expect(mockEventManager.broadcastSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: 'pacienteListModification', content: 'OK'});
                        expect(mockActiveModal.dismissSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
                    })
                )
            );
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `@ViewChild` for `#editForm="ngForm"` so you have easy access to your form after your component has inited. from that point your NgForm would be the same as if you built it with the form builder and you could test like many examples you see online.

I'm currently in search of how to test without doing the ViewChild method, if I find something I'll update you on how to.